# Make a symmetric confidence interval for µ at the 99% confidence level.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> In a sample of $15$ normally distributed random variables with unknown
>   expectation $µ$ and variance $σ^2$, the sample mean was $10.3$ and the
>   sample variance $s^2$ was $0.13.$ Make a symmetric confidence interval
>   for $µ$ at the $99$% confidence level.

Well, the confidence interval is given by

$$\mu=\overline{X}\pm z\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}},$$

where $\Phi(z)=(1+q)/2.$ I have that

$$\Phi(z)=\frac{1+0.99}{2}=0.995 \implies z=\Phi^{-1}(0.995)=??$$

Which one of the ones I've marked should I choose?

The book says $z=2.977,$ which doesn't seem close to what I had in mind. Why this deviation?

[image]

Comment: You need to consult the inverse-phi tables. I dont have them in front of me but i think its 2.5758 from memory...

Comment: Have you seen the picture I've inserted? That's the exact table I'm refering to and there are 7 different values of 0.995 there.

Comment: Yes this is the phi table, but you need the inverse phi table!

Comment: I don't have such a table, it's not in the book. And the book refers to the phi-table only. Also, the answer you got as 2.5758 is wrong according to the book.

Comment: Every sensible book on statistics which deals with the Normal Distribution and confidence intervals has an inverse phi table. The table is easily obtainable from the internet, or you can buy a calculator with all this stuff programmed into it. Books frequently have misprints.

Comment: I agree, the book I have is the second edition of Probability, Statistics and Stochastic Processes, Peter Plofsson and Mikael Andersson. There might be a missprint because an online calculator for computing the z-score agrees with the answer you provided.

Comment: @Parseval This table must show values of a different distribution. You have to read more carefully the text according to the table.

Comment: @Parseval I have checked  this [table](https://books.google.de/books?id=mSnG5C3I-iAC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (p.527) in this book. I cannot believe it. It is denoted as the cdf of the standard normal distribution. This must be a misprint. But it is still not clear why this flaw hasn´t been corrected before printing or afterwards (E-Book).

Comment: But $\Phi(x)$ IS the cdf of the standard normal distribution since $$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-x^2/2} \ dx \quad x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: But the values from the table of the book don´t match.

Comment: How do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Parseval At this ["normal" table](http://math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf) we have $\Phi(2.57)=0.99492$ and $\Phi(2.58)= .99506$. Thus $\Phi^{-1}(0.995)\approx 2.575$. You can obtain a better result by applying $\text{linear interpolation}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrepancy is related to the $t$-distribution. Recall that the cost of replacing an unknown $\sigma^2$ with its estimate $S^2$ is that the resulting quantity
$$\frac{\overline x - \mu}{S / \sqrt n}$$
has a student's $t$-distribution, not a normal distribution. (If you replaced $S$ with $\sigma$, then the quantity would have a normal distribution; also, as $n \to \infty$, the student's $t$-distribution approximates a standard normal distribution.)

As a result, you are consulting the wrong table. You instead need a table of values for a $t$-distribution with 14 df. You can verify that the book's calculator is correct with, for instance, [this calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/t-distribution.aspx) (df = 14, $P(T \leq t) = 0.995$).

Comment: Ah I see now. So everytime my true variance is unknown, but is approximated by a sample, then I have to consult the degrees of fredom table?

Comment: Correct.${}{}{}$

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, thank you Aaron!

Answer (score 1):

I am reliably informed by my calculator that $$\Phi^{-1}(0.995)=2.57582936$$

Comment: You have a great calculator. It can be checked by an online calculator as well.

Comment: I have a Ti-84 Texas instrument. I can also confirm this now.